# Unable to read XML file with characters at the beginning of the document

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from an XML file. The data has characters at the beginning of the document (the document comes this way as I am getting the files from an FTP site) so I am reading as string so that I can pad out the extra characters with code. Now when I open the file in notepad++ or word pad it opens just fine, the problems comes when I want to do it from my program.

I have tried to use both streamreader and File.ReadAllText() methods as I always do but nothing seems to work. When I run it from my code all I get is a few special characters

[View from notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9uX5.png)

```
OpenFileDialog OpenDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
OpenDialog.ShowDialog();
var FileName = OpenDialog.FileName;
var FileString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
```

I have also tried to change the encoding type when  reading from the file but it still doesnt work

Comment: That's not an XML file, its a binary file that happens to contain XML at some point.  That binary preamble should not be there, its nothing to do with text encoding. Do you know *why* its there?  Does it appear if you use an FTP client rather than you own FTP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an XML file. As others explained, it's a binary file that contains XML after some point.

You can still read the XML contents though if you skip the binary part. You can open it eg with a FileStream and a StreamReader and read until you reach the start of the XML text.

```
var tagAsInt=(int)'<';

using(var stream=File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
using(var sr=new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (sr.Peek() !=tagAsInt) 
    {
        sr.Read();
    }

    var xml=new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(sr);
}
```

`Peek()` checks the next character in the stream without consuming it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to strip off those rogue characters from the beginning of the file.  Try this:

```
var sanitizedText = myFileString.Split('<', 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```